# Is it possible to script multiple regex search-and-replace commands in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have recently been having fun using regex successfully in Notepad++'s search and replace box.

However, I now have a short list of lengthy search-and-replacements that I would like to do again to another file later, and rather than enter them manually again, I was hoping I could stick them in a script somewhere and point it at my next file.

Is something like this possible in Notepad++?

If not, please recommend something that *does* support such a scheme.

Comment: Are you asking if Notepad++ itself can be scripted? Or whether you can have Notepad++ apply an external script (say, in Python) to the current file?

Comment: I think he's talking about a Macro.

Comment: I think,you talking about "QuickText" for Notpad++;

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ may not be the best tool for automated operations. I would suggest a scripting language with a powerful regex engine like perl for this use. Please note though that your notepad++ regular expressions may not work with other engines right away.

If you don't want to learn a new language just for this, perhaps you can use Macro recording for this. I never used that feature, but I guess this is what it was designed for ;)

Comment: +1 for mentioning using a scripting language.
-1 for not mentioning the PythonScript plugin which gives the power of python to N++ with direct access to the text along with the N++ and Scintilla commands.